# Destruct object when dereferenced

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, dereference

I have this code ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Foo{
public:
    int *a;
    Foo(int n);
    ~Foo();
    Foo* add(int n);
    void print();
};

Foo::Foo(int n){
    a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *a=n;
}

Foo::~Foo(){
    printf("destructor called\n");
    free(a);
}

Foo* Foo::add(int n){
    return new Foo(*a+n);
}

void Foo::print(){
    printf("foo is =%i\n",*a);
}

int main(){
    Foo* bar = new Foo(1);
    delete bar;
    bar = new Foo(1);
    bar->add(1)->print();
}
```

The output is:

```
destructor called
foo is =2
```

The problem is that the destructor is called only once, and the address returned by `add()` is lost.  I can only destruct it if I first save it to a variable and then call the destructor on it, like this:

```
Foo* temp = bar->add(1);
temp->print();
delete temp;
```

But I think this looks a bit messy, since I will use this new instance only once.

So my question is, is there a way to call the destructor of the returned object of a method if it is dereferenced but not assigned to any variable? So that the destructor in this code gets called correctly?

```
bar->add(1)->print();
```

Comment: Why are you using pointers in the first place?

Comment: It's called *destructor*, not *deconstructor*.  And why are you mixing `malloc/free` with `new/delete`?

Comment: Use smart pointers.

Comment: You want to look at [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/106508/1270789).

Comment: Stop using pointers. The only reason to use pointers is if you want manual control over memory allocation, instead of the default case of automatic behaviour. But now you are saying you want it to happen automatically instead of manually ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `std::unique_ptr`:

```
class Foo{
public:
    std::unique_ptr<int> a;
    Foo(int n);
    ~Foo();
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> add(int n);
    void print();
};

Foo::Foo(int n){
    a = std::make_unique(n);
}
Foo::~Foo(){
    printf("destructor called\n");
}
std::unique_ptr<Foo> Foo::add(int n){
    return std::make_unique<Foo>(*a+n);
}
void Foo::print(){
    printf("foo is =%i\n",*a);
}
int main(){
    auto bar= std::make_unique<Foo>(1);
    bar=std::make_unique<Foo>(1);
    bar->add(1)->print();
}
```

Comment: worked as expected with a = std::make_unique<int>(n); in the constructor, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Chris's answer addresses the particular example you provided.

But, there is no reason to use pointers in that example at all.  The code can be simplified to this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
public:
    int a;

    Foo(int n);
    ~Foo();

    Foo add(int n);
    void print();
};

Foo::Foo(int n){
    a = n;
}

Foo::~Foo(){
    std::cout << "destructor called" << std::endl;
}

Foo Foo::add(int n){
    return Foo(a + n);
}

void Foo::print(){
    std::cout << "foo is =" << a << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    { Foo bar(1); }
    Foo bar(1);
    bar.add(1).print();
}
```